# What does it mean for a set to have additional structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

In my lecture notes, they talk about a system, where the possible configurations of the system are elements from some set A that can have additional structure. But I don't understand what it means for A to have additional structure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The real numbers are a set but you can add a + operation to create a group, a $\times$ operation to extend that to an algebra, a modulus operation to create a topology and so on.

Comment: That'll do as an answer, @Paul.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I think I get it!